gradle could not resolve androidx library in a java-library
I'm working on setting up instrumentation tests in my java library gradle project using the androidx.test library. I added the following dependency in my build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.6.2'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}


However, Gradle is unable to resolve some of its transitive dependencies, resulting in build failures. I’m new to Gradle and not sure how to resolve these missing dependencies.
Here’s the error message I’m getting:
:lib:test: Could not resolve androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0.
Required by:
    project :lib > androidx.test:runner:1.6.2
    project :lib > androidx.test:runner:1.6.2 > androidx.test:monitor:1.7.2

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

What I’ve Tried:

Clearing the Gradle cache.
Invalidate and restart Android Studio.
Checking for the latest version of androidx.test:runner.

None of these steps have resolved the issue.
Questions:

How can I configure Gradle to properly resolve transitive dependencies for androidx.test?
Do I need to manually add missing dependencies, or is there a way to ensure that all required libraries are fetched automatically?

Maven repo link which I am trying to import
Output of ./gradlew :lib:dependencies


        > Task :lib:dependencies

        ------------------------------------------------------------
        Project ':lib'
        ------------------------------------------------------------

        annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
        No dependencies

        api - API dependencies for the 'main' feature. (n)
        No dependencies

        apiElements - API elements for the 'main' feature. (n)
        No dependencies

        compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
        \--- androidx.test:runner:1.6.2
            +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01
            |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.0-beta01
            |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10 -> 1.8.20
            |              +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.20
            |              \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
            +--- androidx.test.services:storage:1.5.0
            |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01 (*)
            |    \--- androidx.test:monitor:1.7.0 -> 1.7.2
            |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01 (*)
            |         +--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0 FAILED
            |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20 (*)
            +--- androidx.test:monitor:1.7.2 (*)
            +--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0 FAILED
            \--- junit:junit:4.13.2
                \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

        compileOnly - Compile-only dependencies for the 'main' feature. (n)
        No dependencies

        compileOnlyApi - Compile-only API dependencies for the 'main' feature. (n)
        No dependencies

        default - Configuration for default artifacts. (n)
        No dependencies

        implementation - Implementation dependencies for the 'main' feature. (n)
        \--- androidx.test:runner:1.6.2 (n)

        mainSourceElements - List of source directories contained in the Main SourceSet. (n)
        No dependencies

        runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
        \--- androidx.test:runner:1.6.2
            +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01
            |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.0-beta01
            |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10 -> 1.8.20
            |              +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.20
            |              \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
            +--- androidx.test.services:storage:1.5.0
            |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01 (*)
            |    \--- androidx.test:monitor:1.7.0 -> 1.7.2
            |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01 (*)
            |         +--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0 FAILED
            |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20 (*)
            +--- androidx.test:monitor:1.7.2 (*)
            +--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0 FAILED
            \--- junit:junit:4.13.2
                \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

        runtimeElements - Runtime elements for the 'main' feature. (n)
        No dependencies

        runtimeOnly - Runtime-only dependencies for the 'main' feature. (n)
        No dependencies

        testAnnotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'test'.
        No dependencies

        testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
        \--- androidx.test:runner:1.6.2
            +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01
            |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.0-beta01
            |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10 -> 1.8.20
            |              +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.20
            |              \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
            +--- androidx.test.services:storage:1.5.0
            |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01 (*)
            |    \--- androidx.test:monitor:1.7.0 -> 1.7.2
            |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01 (*)
            |         +--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0 FAILED
            |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20 (*)
            +--- androidx.test:monitor:1.7.2 (*)
            +--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0 FAILED
            \--- junit:junit:4.13.2
                \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

        testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
        No dependencies

        testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
        No dependencies

        testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
        \--- androidx.test:runner:1.6.2
            +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01
            |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.0-beta01
            |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10 -> 1.8.20
            |              +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.20
            |              \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
            +--- androidx.test.services:storage:1.5.0
            |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01 (*)
            |    \--- androidx.test:monitor:1.7.0 -> 1.7.2
            |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-beta01 (*)
            |         +--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0 FAILED
            |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20 (*)
            +--- androidx.test:monitor:1.7.2 (*)
            +--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0 FAILED
            \--- junit:junit:4.13.2
                \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

        testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
        No dependencies

        (*) - Indicates repeated occurrences of a transitive dependency subtree. Gradle expands transitive dependency subtrees only once per project; repeat occurrences only display the root of the subtree, followed by this annotation.

        (n) - A dependency or dependency configuration that cannot be resolved.

        A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

        BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 666ms
        1 actionable task: 1 executed




These AndroidX libraries are not really meant to be used in common Java projects,
because in general, androidx.test merely belongs into androidTestImplementation,
which means it ultimately depends on AGP, to create that source-set androidTest.
It reads:
+--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.1.0 FAILED

Try to provide a newer version, alike:
androidTestImplementation "androidx.tracing:tracing:1.2.0"


The requested version 1.1.0 would also be available on repository google():
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.tracing/tracing

Declaring dependencies clearly reads androidTestImplementation ...

so I need to apply AGP?
